# Graphics card drops frames when coming from idle state

Tags: graphics-card, lag, 4k-resolution

I recently got a new computer. Upon hooking a 4K monitor to it, the screen occasionally lags. What I've noticed, though, is that it *only* lags directly after the screen image hasn't changed at all for a short period of time. For instance, if the screen is stagnant, and I move my cursor, it lags for a second, catches up, and then runs smoothly again until I stop moving the cursor. Thus, if I put something animated on the screen, it works completely fine, no lag at all.

I then noticed if I opened another window and covered the animation with it, or dragged the animation window off the screen, it *still* ran smoothly. But as soon as I minimized the window with the animation, closed it, or shrunk it to hide the animation, it would suddenly start lagging again, which leads me to believe it's a graphics card setting.

Does anyone know how to disable this 'eco' setting?

Here are the specs:

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Screen: 4K Sceptre U27 LED Monitor
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730
- Motherboard: [msi H81M ECO](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H81M-ECO.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your video cable is plugged into your Graphics Card and not into your motherboard.

Update your Drivers

If that doesn't work, try Disabling On-Board Graphics in your bios.

Turning of Link State Power Management in advanced power settings under PCI Express might help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It is plugged directly into the GPU HDMI port, and all drivers appear up-to-date. I looked in Device Manager > Display Adapters, and I'm only seeing the NVIDIA driver. I also couldn't find an option in the BIOS to disable on-board graphics, and the 'Initiate Graphic Adapter' was already set to PEG and not IGD, which I presume means it's using my NVIDIA card? I added my mobo specs above too, in case it helps.

Comment: Go to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options, Under "Hide Additional plans" select High Performance.

Comment: :-/  nope.. good thought though. I checked the advanced settings too; still couldn't find anything that fixed it.

Comment: Your motherboard is designed to be ECO, but I wonder if it has a high performance setting... or like you asked before, disable ECO mode.